# Spring Data Connection (two level connection) using spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

The Login credentials which I require to connect to database A is stored in different database B.

How can I retrieve those Credentials from database B and connect to database A?

I need this to be achieved via Springboot

Answer (score -1):

You must to use two datasources. 
Take a look at following post, it helps me

https://medium.com/@joeclever/using-multiple-datasources-with-spring-boot-and-spring-data-6430b00c02e7

The main idea is to create two datasource configurations and point them to the corresponding package:

```
package com.foobar;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
  basePackages = { "com.foobar.foo.repo" }
)
public class FooDbConfig {

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "dataSource")
  @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
  public DataSource dataSource() {
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean 
  entityManagerFactory(
    EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
    @Qualifier("dataSource") DataSource dataSource
  ) {
    return builder
      .dataSource(dataSource)
      .packages("com.foobar.foo.domain")
      .persistenceUnit("foo")
      .build();
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(
    @Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory 
    entityManagerFactory
  ) {
    return new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
  }
}
```